# AttachConsole(...) alternative for Windows8

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, console

AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) returns TRUE and GetLastError() returns ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED when running console (ie parent process is cmd.exe) application on Windows8. Is there any alternative which can be used with this OS?

Comment: Don't call GetLastError() if a winapi function didn't fail.

Comment: From the documentation, `AttachConsole` returns `true` when it _succeeds_. What's the problem?

Comment: yep, GetLastError() messed up the things - AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) && GetLastError() == 0,
however it returns 0 with previous windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

The value of GetLastError is random if AttachConsole returns true (ie, successful calls to AttachConsole or indeed any Win32 API function won't reset the last error code). Only check for the error code if it was set.

Comment: actually another problem that the application does not wait untill exectuion in attached console finish, not happen with XP for instance